# Keeping track of boolean data

Tags: c++, list, boolean, bit

I need to keep track of n samples. The information I am keeping track of is of boolean type, i.e. something is true or false. As soon as I am on sample n+1, i basically want to ignore the oldest sample and record information about the newest one.

So say I keep track of samples, I may have something like

OLDEST 0   0   1   1  0   NEWEST

If the next sample is 1, this will become

OLDEST 0   1   1   0  1   NEWEST

if the next one is 0, this will become...

OLDEST 1   1   0   1  0   NEWEST

So what is the best way to implement this in terms of simplicity and memory?

Some ideas I had:

> > Vector of bool (this would require shifting elements so seems expensive)
> >     Storing it as bits...and using bit shifting (memorywise --cheap? but is there a limit on the number of samples?)
> >     Linked lists? (might be an overkill for the task)

Thanks for the ideas and suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect use of a ring buffer. Unfortunately there isn't one in the standard library, but you could use boost.

Alternately roll your own using a fixed-length `std::list` and `splice` the head node to the tail when you need to overwrite an old element.

Answer (score 2):

You want a set of bits. Maybe you can look into a std::bitset

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitset.html

Very straightfoward to use, optimal memory consumption and probably the best performance

The only limitation is that you need to know at compile-time the value of n. If you want to set it on runtime, have a look at boost http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how many samples you want to keep.
`vector<bool>` could be a valid option; I would expect an
`erase()` on the first element to be reasonably efficient.
Otherwise, there's `deque<bool>`.  If you know how many elements
you want to keep at compile time, `bitset<N>` is probably better
than either.

In any case, you'll have to wrap the standard container in some
additional logic; none have the actual logic you need (that of
a ring buffer).

Answer (score 0):

If you only need 8 bits... then use a char and do logical shifts "<<, >>" and do a mask to look at the one you need.

- 16 Bits - short
- 32 Bits - int
- 64 Bits - long
- etc...

Example:

Oldest 00110010 Newest -> Oldest 1001100101 Newest

Done by:

```
char c = 0x32; // 50 decimal or 00110010 in binary
c<<1; // Logical shift left once.
c++; // Add one, sense LSB is the newest.

//Now look at the 3rd newest bit
print("The 3rd newest bit is: %d\n", (c & 0x4));
```

Simple and EXTREMELY cheap on resources. Will be VERY VERY high performance.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it's not clear what you intend to do with the samples. If all you care about is storing the N most recent samples, you could try the following. I'll do it for "chars" and let you figure out how to optimize for "bool" should you need that.

```
char buffer[N];
int samples = 0;

void record_sample( char value )
{
  buffer[samples%N] = value;
  samples = samples + 1;
}
```

Once you've stored N samples (once you've called record_sample N times) you can read the oldest and newest samples like so:

```
char oldest_sample()
{
  return buffer[samples%N];
}

char newest_sample()
{
  return buffer[(samples+N-1)%N];
}
```

Things get a little trickier if you intend to read the oldest sample before you've already stored N samples - but not that much trickier. For that, you want a "ring buffer" which you can find in boost and on wikipedia.